# throw 'You must provide an appId and masterKey!';

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I am migrating my application from parse and going through `parse-migration guide`.

I executed parse-server-example locally given on https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example and it works fine but after that I tried to run parse-server from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server but that show error as

```
throw 'You must provide an appId and masterKey!';
```

on command prompt.

Added mongodb url and other keys in index.js and DataAdapter.js but I dont know where do I add values for master key and app Id.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have to download `parse-server` manually from github. Most often that is handled by npm. The `parse-server-example` you mentioned already uses `parse-server` to get a basic app up and running. `parse-server-example` is a good starting point for building out your own application and you never have to "switch" to something else.

The error you are seeing is because you don't provide an appId and masterKey in the parse configuration. This is copied from `parse-server-example` and is what the config object should look like.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337'  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
});
```

Parse Server is just another npm module so I recommend reading up on nodejs and npm before using it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but try this in your prompt:

```
export API_KEY=foo
export MASTER_KEY=bar
```

(just replace `foo` and `bar` by your own keys of course.)
Then, `npm start` again and it will works fine.